# Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api, client

I am calling my web api from my C# desktop client.

This is my code on the client:

```
public IEnumerable<Model.Print> Get()
{
    var print = new List<Model.Print>();

    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri(Shared.URL);
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue(Shared.HeaderType));
        var response = client.GetAsync(route + "?" + GeneralTags.CUSTOMER_REF + "=" + new Guid().ToString()).Result;

        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            string strJson = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            var jObj2 = (IEnumerable<Model.Print>)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(strJson);
        }
        else
        {
            evError(new Exception(String.Format("{0}: {1}", (int)response.StatusCode, response.ReasonPhrase)), ErrorTags.PRINT_GET);
        }
    }
    return print;
}
```

But I get an error on this line:

```
var jObj2 = (IEnumerable<Model.Print>)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(strJson);
```

The error is:

```
'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[InformedWorkerServer.Model.Print]'.
```

The strJson contains a value:

```
[
  {"PrintId":1,"PrintRef":"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000","Header":"header","TC":"tc","CompanyRef":"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"},
  {"PrintId":2,"PrintRef":"39a10cee-7cb3-4ed3-aec2-293761eed96d","Header":"header","TC":"tc","CompanyRef":"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"}]
```

What am i missing?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>` instead:

```
var jObj2 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Model.Print>>(strJson);
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. This does work on Desktop but not on Raspberry PI2 - which i did not stipulate. But it worked for this forum. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

If you would like to format the nested json structure as represented in the image below. you can make use of the below formatter in [Newtonsoft.Json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J0KjP.jpg).

[image]

Solution : 
**var _addressDetails = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject>(Convert.ToString(data.addressDetails));**